# How to add custom property with mongoose ref

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to add custom property 'priority' so that I can map my Field collection with the Attribute collection. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4Eje.png)

To get output like this one [But with priorities after attribute_name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXbp7.png)